# Provide menu link when creating node programmatically and append it to parent menu link

Tags: nodes, 9

I am creating a `Node` programatically:

```
Node::create([
  'title' => "Some name",
  'type' => "people",
  'body' => $params['body'],
  'field_people_degree' => $params['field_people_degree'],
  'field_people_email' => $params['field_people_email'],
  'field_field_image' => ['target_id' => $this->createImageFile($params['field_field_image'], $params['field_pub_tool_id'])->id()],
  'field_people_first_name' => $params['field_people_first_name'],
  'field_people_last_name' => $params['field_people_last_name'],
  'field_people_phone' => $params['field_people_phone'],
  'field_people_position' => $params['field_people_position'],
]);
```

and now I want to provide a menu link and append it under certain parents `about-us`>`people`>`scientists`.
[image]

I tried this:

```
  MenuLinkContent::create([
    'title' => 'Some name',
    'link' => ['uri' => 'entity:about-us/people/scientists/some-name'],
    'menu_name' => 'main',
    'weight' => 0,
  ])->save();
```

but it crashes the DB. Any help?

Comment: `entity:about-us/people/scientists/some-name` - this cannot work, maybe you mean `entity:ENTITY_TYPE/ENTITY_ID`. For URL schemas see e.g. [Url::fromUri](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromUri/8.6.x)

Comment: @Hudri thanks for your comment. So is entity type in this case `people`? And entity id the id of the created node?

Comment: Entity type is node, entity ID is the node ID

Comment: @Clive could you help me with how I then set a custom URL alias and put the menu link under the following parents:
- about-us
    - people
         - scientists
?